# 3-piece dissection of square to equilateral triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, open-problems

At a workshop it was suggested that it likely remains an open problem
whether or not there is a 3- <strike>or 2</strike> -piece 
[dissection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dissection.html)
of a square to an equilateral triangle.
Can anyone confirm that this is unresolved?

Four-piece dissections are known, the most famous being
Henry Dudeney's century-old gem:

[image]
[image]

               

<sub>[Maple animation from this
[link](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=6499).]</sub>

Comment: 2 is not possible because the side length of the triangle is more than the diagonal of the square.

Comment: I just want to tell that applet to "hold still, dammit"! 

Comment: @Todd: Added a stable image (in a different orientation).

Comment: Wow, ask and ye shall receive! Thank you, Joseph!

Comment: A 3-piece dissection of the equilateral triangle would have to create 4 right angles to serve as corners of the square, and there are just a few ways this can be done. At first glance, none of them recombine as a square (though you can get a rectangle). It should be pretty easy to run through the options and rule them all out.

Comment: I comment only to point out that the so-called Dudeney construction may not, in fact, be due to H. Dudeney. For more details, see G.N. Frederickson's "Hinged Dissections: Swinging and Twisting" (pp. 8-10). http://books.google.com/books?id=pW_0EisSP4IC&lpg=PR9&ots=9B2Po0jPx5&dq=dissecting%20%22equilateral%20triangle%20into%20a%20square%22&lr&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @AntonLukyanenko I don't follow your argument. If we dissect the square with corners (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) using the curves $y=x(1-x)$ and $y=x(x-1)+1$, then we get three pieces and no right angles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the paper, "Dissection with the Fewest Pieces is Hard, Even to Approximate" ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.06706), [doi](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-48532-4_4)) by Bosboom et al., they write:

> We have known for centuries how to dissect any polygon $P$ into any other polygon $Q$ of equal area, that is, how to cut $P$ into finitely many pieces and re-arrange the pieces to form $Q$. But we know relatively little about how many pieces are necessary. **For example, it is unknown whether a square can be dissected into an equilateral triangle using fewer than four pieces.** [emphasis added]

The authors seem to be knowledgeable about the subject, so I'd be inclined to trust their claim.  As I mentioned in [another MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345397/), they point out that more generally, it is not known if "$k$ piece dissection," the problem of deciding whether two given polygons (say with rational vertices) admit a common dissection into at most $k$ pieces, is decidable. The trouble is that even if you restrict yourself to cuts that are piecewise-linear, there is no known a priori upper bound on how many "zigs and zags" a cut might have to take.