# Geometric dissection theory

Tags: discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

A few days ago, i realized that one way to prove the Pythagorean Theorem is to dissect the given right-angled triangle into 2 triangles similar to it, and apply well-known properties of ratios of areas.
So this fundamental theorem can be viewed as a consequence of the possibility to dissect a given right-triangle into 2 similar sub-triangles.

My question is: Which branch of geometry systematically studies dissections of general polygons (or other shapes) into other sub-polygons (sub-shapes) of a given type, and the metrical properties that emerge as consequences of these dissections?

My search is on-going, i have seen some relevant results & books, for example the problem of dissecting a random triangle into n similar triangles, and books on discrete & combinatorial geometry that border on the subject (but not studied them yet), so i'm asking for some further guidance towards a systematic exposition of the relevant theory, in 2D, 3D or more dimensions..

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but possibly relevant to your interests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace%E2%80%93Bolyai%E2%80%93Gerwien_theorem

Comment: The proof you give in your first paragraph, I call the one line proof of Pythagoras' Theorem, the one line being the one you have to draw to dissect the triangle.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: A relevant discussion in hsm.stackexchange at which you may want to take a look later on: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/on-einsteins-proof-of-the-so-called-pythagorean-theorem

Answer (score 5):

You might search for 'scissors congruence', which discusses which polyhedra (= higher-dimensional analogues of polygons) can be cut up to make which other ones.  The question of whether you can cut a cube into finitely many pieces and reassemble to make a regular tetrahedron of the same volume was on [Hilbert's problem list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_problems) of around 1900, and was one of the first to be solved (when Dehn showed that [it can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant)).  I am not sure that this is exactly the sort of thing that you are looking for, but it is related and it's an interesting area of mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

The following paper proves (1) that every polygon may be partitioned (dissected)
into (a finite number of) non-obtuse triangles, and (2) into acute triangles:

> Maehara, Hiroshi. "Acute triangulations of polygons." *European Journal of Combinatorics* 23, no. 1 (2002): 45-55.
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---

Dissections specifically into similar triangles:

> Jones, C. A., P. Jones, and A. B. Bolt. "Dissections of triangles into five similar triangles." *The Mathematical Gazette* 82, no. 494 (1998): 225-234.
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---

See also:

- [MathWorld on Triangle Dissection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleDissection.html).
- The textbook [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/DCG/) has a chapter on polygon dissections.
- MO question: [3-piece dissection of square to equilateral triangle?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/80101/6094)
- MO question: [Inside-out polygonal dissections](https://mathoverflow.net/q/186332/6094).