# Decision problems for which it is unknown whether they are decidable

Tags: soft-question, big-list, computability-theory, computer-science, open-problems

In computability theory, what are examples of decision problems of which it is not known whether they are [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)?

Comment: My (unpublished) dissertation has an example, see ArXiv 1408.2784 for details. Briefly, given a string representing a hyperidentity (clone equation or restricted second order logic universal equality) and a finite similarity type (set of function symbols), does the logically equivalent infinite set of first order identities have a finite logically equivalent subset? If you restrict the problem by fixing the identity, (e.g. ask just for hyperassociativity and vary the type) the answer is yes, but not uniformly in the hyperidentity.  Gerhard "Should Get Back To That" Paseman, 2019.11.06.

Comment: There are many ineffective results in number theory that can be converted into an answer to your question. For example, given an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb Q$, and an integer $r$, is the [rational Mordell-Weil] rank of the elliptic curve equal to $r$? Or how about this: Given a curve of genus at least 2 over $\mathbb Q$ and a list of rational points on the curve, is there any other rational point on the curve?

Comment: This question is nearly a [duplicate](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/18846) of a question on cstheory.stackexchange.com. (Joseph O'Rourke mentions this fact in his answer below, but it seems worth putting a comment here at the top of the page.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

An *integer linear recurrence sequence* is a sequence $x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots$ of integers that obeys a linear recurrence relation
$$x_n = a_1 x_{n-1} + a_2 x_{n-2} + \cdots + a_d x_{n-d}$$
for some integer $d\ge 1$, some integer coefficients $a_1, \ldots, a_d$, and all $n\ge d$.  The following problem is sometimes known as "Skolem's problem":

> Given $d$, $a_1, \ldots, a_d$, $x_0, \ldots x_{d-1}$, does there exist $n$ such that $x_n=0$ ?

It is unknown whether the above problem is undecidable.  For more information, see [Terry Tao's blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/05/25/open-question-effective-skolem-mahler-lech-theorem/) on the subject.

Answer (score 30):

In [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), the problem of deciding whether a given pattern with finitely many live cells is a [Garden of Eden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden_(cellular_automaton)) (i.e. whether it lacks a predecessor).

The main obstacle is that there could be a pattern which has finitely many live cells and a predecessor, but such that all of its predecessors have infinitely many live cells. If we knew there were no such patterns then the problem would be decidable.

**Added 2019 December 3:** Having learnt about the problem from this post, [Ville Salo](https://mathoverflow.net/users/123634/ville-salo) and [Ilkka Törmä](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66104/ilkka-t%C3%B6rm%C3%A4) have produced a paper ("[Gardens of Eden in the Game of Life](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00692)") showing that this problem is decidable. Interestingly, they don't proceed via the method I suggested here. It remains an open problem to determine if there is a non-Garden-of-Eden pattern with finitely many live cells all of whose predecessors have infinitely many live cells.

**Added 2022 January 18:** In fact it is *false* that a finite pattern without finite predecessors must necessarily be a Garden of Eden. This result is [also due to Salo and Törmä](https://www.conwaylife.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=140453#p140453).

Comment: Is your last sentence supposed to be easy to see? Suppose I could prove that every pattern with a predecessor has a predecessor with finitely many cells. How would the Garden of Eden algorithm go? Naively I would try exhaustively searching all possible predecessor patterns. This would uncover a predecessor if a predecessor exists, but if a predecessor does not exist, then how do I know when to stop and declare that no predecessor exists?

Comment: Timothy Chow: by compactness a finite subpattern has no preimage. CA are continuous in Cantor topology.

Comment: I wasn't aware this is open, can't you just add 1s in the complement of a large rectangle in the preimage and play around with the border to avoid births there? Maybe the playing around doesn't work out. Is this question from some reference?

Comment: @TimothyChow As Ville Salo said, by compactness a Garden of Eden must contain an "orphan", a finite set of cells whose states cannot be achieved no matter how the other cells are filled in. Orphans are decidable because one can check all possible assignments to the cells in the neighbourhoods of the orphan's cells. So one would decide a Garden of Eden by alternatingly trying to find a predecessor and trying to prove that an $n\times n$ box around the pattern gave an orphan.

Comment: @VilleSalo That is indeed the obvious proof strategy, but nobody yet has found a "playing around" scheme that always works. I'm afraid there's no reference.

Comment: Ok. Indeed it seems it is non-trivial, so probably it is hard (I have played around with the still life SFT and we can't really solve anything).

Comment: @OscarCunningham - suppose you knew there were no such patterns... how could you choose a sufficient value of `n`?

Comment: @TLW You try all values of $n$ increasingly. For each $n\times n$ box centred on the pattern you try to find a predecessor of the pattern all of whose live cells are in the box, and if that doesn't work you try to prove the box is an orphan. If neither of these succeeds then you increase $n$ and try again. Eventually you must succeed one way or the other since if the pattern has a predecessor it has a predecessor with finitely many live cells (which your box will eventually contain), and if it doesn't then it has an orphan (which your box will eventually contain).

Comment: This nice problem was screaming to be solved. After obsessing about this for a few days, I found Ilkka Törmä obsessing about it across the corridor. We wrote a paper about it https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00692

Comment: We also proved that the "playing around" strategy discussed above can not be used. We periodize instead.

Comment: @VilleSalo Nice work! I'm still digesting your paper, but I noticed that the first two parts of your Question 1 "Does every finite-support configuration in the image of the Game of Life have a finite-support preimage? A co-finite-support preimage?" can be proved equivalent, because you can convert between the two kinds of preimage using a construction like the pattern shown in [this post](https://conwaylife.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=51352#p51352). Also I noticed a typo in Lemma 1; $R$ is used before it's defined.

Comment: You are entirely correct about finite vs cofinite. We "knew" this, but somehow we didn't realize this in the context of the question. Very quickly spotted! (While we're dissecting the paper: there's an accidental claim that Gardens of Eden and orphans are polytime equivalent, but we only have a reduction in one direction. Will fix.)

Comment: Interesting that both here on MO and over on CS Theory StackExchange, the second most highly upvoted answer got solved as a result of the publicity it gained from being posted!

Answer (score 18):

In response to this CompSciTheory ([cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)) question,
[A simple problem whose decidability is not known](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/18846/337)
,
I [posted](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/32797/337) that:

> It is unknown whether or not
>   [it is decidable to determine if a given shape can tile the plane](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/32538/337),

referring to an earlier cstheory question.
This is even open for polyomino tiles.

---

[image: Tiling]

          

<sup>(Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino#Tiling_the_plane_with_copies_of_a_single_polyomino).)</sup>

---

Comment: I think this is known to be decidable now, see Siddhartha Bhattacharya, Periodicity and decidability of tilings of Z^2, https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05738, which is published now in the American Journal of Mathematics.

Comment: @JeremiasEpperlein: Thanks; I was unaware of this paper. Abstract: "As a consequence, the problem whether a given finite set $F$ tiles $\mathbb{Z^2}$ is decidable." Curiously he does not state this in the body of the paper, only: "Corollary 1.2. The problem whether a given finite set $F$ tiles $\mathbb{Z^2}$ by translations is decidable."

Comment: @Rourke I see, if you allow rotations of the tiles then I think the problem is still open. I am also not sure about tilings of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in contrast to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Answer (score 17):

One problem about decidability that continues to attract a lot of attention is extensions of [Hilbert's 10th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) to other rings of number-theoretic interest, especially the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. See for instance this nice [survey paper](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/aws2003.pdf) of Poonen.

Answer (score 17):

The *word problem* for a finitely presented group $G = \langle A \mid R \rangle $ and the associated canonical homomorphism $\pi : F_A \to G$, asks: given an element $w \in F_A$, do we have $\pi(w) = 1$? There exists finitely presented groups in which the word problem is undecidable, a result independently due to Novikov and Boone.

However, W. Magnus showed that for *one-relator groups*, i.e. groups $G = \langle A \mid w= 1 \rangle$ with a single defining relation, the word problem is always decidable (though the time-complexity of this solution remains unknown in general as far as I am aware).

The following natural problem, however, remains open:

> Is the word problem always decidable for two-relator groups $G = \langle A \mid w_1 = 1, w_2 = 1 \rangle$?

This appears in the [Kourovka Notebook](https://kourovka-notebook.org/) as Problem 9.29.

There are also concrete examples of groups for which we do not know whether their word problem is decidable or not. For example, we know very little about how to solve the word problem in [most Artin groups](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ejon.mccammond/papers/mysterious-geometry.pdf). The following is an open problem which appears in the previous link:

> Let $G = \langle a, b, c, d \mid aba=bab, ad = da, bdb = dbd, aca = cac, bcb = cbc, cdc = dcd\rangle$.
>
> Is the word problem for $G$ decidable?

It is somewhat surprising that this problem is open -- if one considers the *semigroup* presentation with the same generators and the same defining relations, then the word problem (appropriately phrased as the problem of comparing two words) is easily solvable!

Comment: That's a really nice answer, and surprising, thanks Carl-Fredrik!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen Thank you -- it is indeed surprising. A closely related problem you may be interested in is the fact that the word problem for one-relation semigroups $\langle A \mid u = v \rangle$ remains a long-standing open problem.

Comment: amazing - do you happen to know who formulated that problem first?

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen The word problem goes back to Dehn in the early 1910s, but Adjan in the 1960s looked a great deal at one-relation semigroups in particular, reducing it to a number of cases (and also solving the word problem for one-relator semigroups $\langle A \mid u = 1 \rangle$).

Comment: Thanks Carl-Fredrik!

Comment: Wow, you wrote this entire answer without mentioning B. B. Newman! Amazing!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Another decision problem which remains open is the conjugacy problem for torsion-free one-relator groups. The conjugacy problem is the problem of deciding whether two given elements are conjugate or not -- it is clearly at least as hard as the word problem. It was solved in 1968 for one-relator groups with torsion by...

Answer (score 12):

[$k$-Piece Dissection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.06706.pdf) is not known to be decidable.  Given two polygons and an integer $k$, is there a dissection of the first polygon into k pieces that can be reassembled into the second one?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem they ask is. Do I interpret correctly that it is open whether, given two *rational* polygons of equal area in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is decidable whether there is a common dissection?

Comment: @VilleSalo : I had the same question. I have not asked the authors, but I assume that that is what they meant.

Comment: @VilleSalo I noticed today that in Section 9 of the paper, the authors write, "Our proofs remain valid when the input polygons are restricted to be simple (hole-free) and orthogonal with all edges having integer length." They also write, "Is k-Piece Dissection in NP, or even decidable? We do not know the answer to this question even when only orthogonal cuts are allowed and rotations and reflections are forbidden."

Comment: Ok, but "integer length edges" still allows uncountably many polygons.

Comment: Concretely (and I apologize for this triviality): Suppose the polygons are given by Turing machines telling you better and better precision on the angles and positions of edges (I mean, how else, when no specific type of algebraicity is specified?) Consider two unit cubes that have been slightly distorted (still with unit sides) by pushing two corners together. You can never know if two such polygons are the same (and it's easy to arrange that they have no common $k$-dissection for any $k$ when distinct).

Comment: @VilleSalo They said, "*orthogonal* with all edges having integer length." I think that "orthogonal" means that every edge is either parallel to the $x$-axis or parallel to the $y$-axis.

Comment: Ah, I missed this word. If the last sentence really means that both the polygon and cuts are orthogonal, I don't see why it would be trivially decidable, but this is highly surprising. With this interpretation, I can finally upvote this answer :P

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps the biggest open problem in symbolic dynamics is the equivalence problem for subshifts of finite type.

Given a finite alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ and a finite set $\mathcal{F}$ of finite words over $\mathcal{A}$ (the *forbidden words*), the corresponding *subshift of finite type* consists of

- The space $S\subseteq \mathcal{A}^\mathbb{Z}$ of all bi-infinite words over $\mathcal{A}$ that do not have any of the forbidden words as subwords, and
- The *shift map* $\sigma \colon S\to S$ that shifts each symbol to the left one spot.

Two subshifts $(S,\sigma)$ and $(S',\sigma')$ of finite type are *equivalent* if they are conjugate as dynamical systems, i.e. if there exists a homeomorphism $h\colon S\to S'$ such that $h\circ \sigma = \sigma'\circ h$.

> Is there an algorithm to determine whether two subshifts of finite type $(S,\sigma)$ and $(S',\sigma')$ are equivalent?

See [M. Boyle, Open problems in symbolic dynamics. *Contemporary mathematics* **469** (2008): 69-118.](https://www.math.umd.edu/~mboyle/papers/openfinalsub3nov2007.pdf)

A solution to this problem was famously published in the *Annals of Mathematics* by R. F. Williams in a [1973 paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970908).  An error was found in his proof, so the correctness of his main classification algorithm became the "Williams conjecture".  This conjecture was disproven by K. H. Kim and F. W. Roush in 1990's in a series of [two](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-1992-1130528-4) [papers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/120975), and at present we have essentially no idea whether equivalence is decidable.

Answer (score 5):

It remains open whether the won-position problem of infinite chess is decidable, the problem of determining whether a given finite position in infinite chess is winning for white or not. See Richard Stanley's question at [https://mathoverflow.net/q/27967](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27967/1946). Meanwhile, the [mate-in-$n$ problem of infinite chess is decidable](http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-mate-in-n-problem-of-infinite-chess-is-decidable/), and so the open part of the problem necessarily concerns positions with infinite game value.

Also open is the optimal-play problem: given a won position, is a given move optimal?

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by a previous (now deleted) post:

We do not know if every even natural number (at least four) is a [sum of two primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) [Goldbach, 1742]. However, there is a simple algorithm that decides if a *given* even number (at least four) is a sum of two primes.

Similarly but differently, we do not know if every even natural number is a [difference of two primes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111196/name-of-a-conjecture-on-difference-of-prime-numbers) [Maillet, 1905].  Here there is no (known) algorithm that decides if a *given* even number is a difference of two primes.

These are the examples given in *Gödel, Escher, Bach* to teach the reader about the difference between bounded and unbounded search.

---

After a few searches, ending [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00187v3), I found that there are more difficult, and earlier, versions of Maillet's question.  Kronecker [1901] asks if every even natural number is the difference of two primes in infinitely many ways.  Polignac [1849] asks if every even natural number is the difference of infinitely many pairs of *consecutive* primes.  These two conjectures have their related decision problems.  However, now the unbounded search is much worse...