# Dissection of polygons into triangles with least number of intermediate pieces

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

This wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace%E2%80%93Bolyai%E2%80%93Gerwien_theorem shows the dissection of a square into a triangle via 4 intermediate pieces. It appears easy to form a cyclic quadrilateral that can be dissected into a triangle with only 2 intermediate pieces.
By the WBG theorem, for dissection from any polygon to any other polygon of same area can be done via a finite number of pieces.

**Question:** Which convex quadrilateral is the hardest to dissect into a triangle - in the sense that the least number of intermediate pieces needed for dissecting it into *some* triangle of the same area is the maximum (the triangle itself could be freely chosen to minimize the number of pieces)?

**Remark:** Indeed, if a quad or in general, a convex *m*-gon is to be dissected into some polygon with *n* sides, the least number of pieces needed has an upper bound that is a function of *m* and *n* (iow, the minimum number of intermediate pieces cannot be arbitrarily high for *any* dissection) - this appears to follow from the proof of WBG theorem given in above wiki page, where the dissection proceeds via an intermediate rectangle of unit width. Our question asks for a tighter upper bound in the case where *n* = 3.

A wider algorithmic question could also be asked where a given *m*-gon is to be dissected into *some* equal area polygon with only its number of sides *n* fixed such that the number of intermediate pieces is minimized - the question above is of course, the case *m* = 4, *n*=3.

**Guess:** The 'minimal intermediate pieces dissection' of any convex m-gon into any convex n-gon is always such that all intermediate pieces are convex.

Comment: Just adding a possibly relevant link: [3-piece dissection of square to equilateral triangle?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/80101/6094).